# Unknown behaviour of assignment op in C

Tags: c, boolean, assignment-operator

I don't know exactly cases of true and false returning from this construction. Can you describe it? Sry, if it is in a google search, I have not found.

```
( (struct->param = param_init()) == NULL )
```

Comment: The return value from the function is being A) stored in `struct->param` and B) compared with `NULL`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: [1) function call --> 2) assignment ] - wrapped by `()`, then the comparison.

Comment: You have not found any C textbook? Even good ol' K&R would work.

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Operator preceedence is not really a problem here, because the assignment is parenthetised.

Comment: @toohonestforthissite that's why it is a comment, not an answer,

Comment: @SouravGhosh: Ok, I should know the table by now. But it won't help OP, because he seems to lack the basics and the table does not really explain the operators. That's the problem with people trying to learn C from YT videos or obscure websites/blogs/tuturials.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`param_init()` this statement will be evaluated first and output will be stored in `struct->param`.
 if `struct->param` contains `NULL`, if conditional will be evaluated to  `true`
or if `struct->param` contains `non NULL`, if conditional will be evaluated to `false`.

Comment: Identical to the user3386109's answer, ty :)

Comment: Corrections: `param_init()` is not a statement. "if struct->param contains NULL" - it's not guaranteed the assignment operator reads the LHS value or just passes the RHS value. This can become problematic for a `volatile` LHS. And `NULL` is a macro, it doesn't even exist at run-time. Being correct helps beginners to understand the rules behind this. Not that it can't be done even by a beginner who learned the languages in a structured way.

Answer (score 1):

```
if ( (struct1->param = param_init()) == NULL )
```

is an obfuscated way of writing

```
struct1->param = param_init();
if(struct1->param == NULL)
{
  ...
}
```

Use the latter form, assignment inside conditions should be avoided.

Comment: *assignment inside conditions should be avoided.* please explain why. It is similar to say *ternary operator should be avoided* as it is inline.

Comment: @tilz0R Because 1) it is a bad idea to have side-effects inside non-related expressions, and 2) it is a bad idea in general to spam as many operators as possible into a single expression, and 3) `=` and `==` can be mixed up.

Comment: 3) That's why experienced programmers write `NULL == variable` :)

Comment: @tilz0R I take it you mean experienced Jedi warriors? The "Yoda conditions" are long since obsolete. They became obsolete in 1989 when Borland released TC - a compiler which was able to warn against using `=` inside conditions. You would get "possible incorrect assignment".

Comment: Then is point 3) useless if compiler warns you. In fact, it warns you if you use `=` operator without parentheses.

Comment: @tilz0R Every experienced programmer already knows of the = inside conditions issue. I won't have this debate yet again. Instead, you go study _any_ professional coding standard, for example [CERT C](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/EXP51-J.+Do+not+perform+assignments+in+conditional+expressions).

Comment: This is my last comment. In your link, *compliant solution* includes: `if ((a = b) == true)` which is the same as OP posted. So point *3* has no real meaning.

Comment: Assignment inside conditions can be useful for a `while` loop condition in order to avoid repeating the assignment.

Answer (score 0):

As assignment operator is having lowest priority that's why it always executes at last ,so in first Parentheses the function param_init() will get call first and the return value of this function will get assigned to structure pointer struct->param and at last value of struct->param will get compared with 0(NULL) and result(either 0 or 1) will return .
NOTE : Removal of Parentheses will change the result as it changes the precedence .